# Pin pointing what I need to change in Foundation CSS for background color of panels?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Another Foundation based question. In the mass of code I received as part of the download, I cannot find where to change the background color of a specific panel?

This is the section of code that I need to change the background for.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <div class="panel">
        <h3>Innovations in Development</h3>
        <p>Text Text Text</p>
        <p>Products currently in different stages of development are:</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
            <p>Product A</p>
        </div>
            <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
                <p>Product B</p>
            </div>
            <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
                <p>Product C</p>
            </div>        
                </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know if you NEED the whole of the CSS file, but I cannot figure out how to find where I need to go to fix the background of the panel I'm wanting to change. I tried

```
.row.large-12_columns.panel {
background-color: blue !important;
}
```

I only added the '!important' because I saw on another question that can override other code?

I'd post a picture of the panel I'm talking about, but I cannot until I hit 10 rep.

Thank you!

EDIT:

All of you were very helpful! Thank you so much! I'd upvote you if I could! I must say, the speedy responses are saving my life, and the patience with the naive questions is incredible. Thank you so much!

Comment: When I need to see what element to work with, I use Chrome's Web Inspector (F12).    Or just right  click on the webpage, and choose "Inspect Element" -- it'll highlight it for you.   On the lower right will be a list of all the CSS rules that apply to it.   You can tinker with them there, or just read the bottom bottom to see the element dom path it is listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need spaces between all of your classes.

```
.row .large-12.columns .panel {
background-color: blue !important;
}
```

When you have two selectors together without a space, you "Chain" the selectors. In this instance, you can have .large-12 and .columns chained, because they're classes on the same object.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your CSS. `<div class="large-12 columns">` has two classes i.e. `.large-12` and `.columns`. You're using `.row.large-12_columns.panel` instead of `.row .large-12.columns .panel` when specifying the CSS. Try this:

```
.row .large-12.columns .panel {
     background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```css
.row .large-12.columns .panel {
     background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <div class="panel">
        <h3>Innovations in Development</h3>
        <p>Text Text Text</p>
        <p>Products currently in different stages of development are:</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
            <p>Product A</p>
        </div>
            <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
                <p>Product B</p>
            </div>
            <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
                <p>Product C</p>
            </div>        
                </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be   `div.large-12>div.panel`  or `div.large-12 div.panel` ?   (I always mixmatch/confuse the `>` for children).

Comment: @jason That's correct as well, one can use it as `div.row>div.large-12.columns>div.panel`.